# Will it work ? MPU6050 Gyro etc. etc. module

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer

Will this code read the values properly ?
Using [MPU6050.h](https://github.com/sparkfun/MPU-9150_Breakout/blob/master/firmware/MPU6050/MPU6050.h).

```
#include <MPU6050.h>
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  MPU6050.initialize();
}

void loop() {
  MPU6050.getWaitForExternalSensorEnabled();
  float X = getRotationX();
  float Y = getRotationY();
  float Z = getRotationZ();
  Serial.print("X:");
  Serial.println(X);
  Serial.print("Y:");
  Serial.println(Y);
  Serial.print("Z:");
  Serial.println(Z);
}
```

Please be patient. I know nothing about gyroscope's working.
I'm stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code would normally look like this

```
#include <MPU6050.h>
#include <Wire.h>

MPU6050 mpu;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  mpu.initialize();
}

void loop() {

  //what is this doing for you?
  mpu.getWaitForExternalSensorEnabled();

  if(mpu.getIntDataReadyStatus() == 1) { 
        float X = mpu.getRotationX();
        float Y = mpu.getRotationY();
        float Z = mpu.getRotationZ();
        Serial.print("X:");
        Serial.println(X);
        Serial.print("Y:");
        Serial.println(Y);
        Serial.print("Z:");
        Serial.println(Z);    
  } else
  {
        Serial.println("MPU not ready");    
  }


}
```